# How should I use Two Step and/or Two Factor authentication with many Apple accounts?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, two-step-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have the following accounts

- A personal iCloud account that secures my keychain / Facetime
- A personal iTunes account
- A work developer account for the App Store (not shared, I exclusively use it)

**Question**

How can I enable [Two Step](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152), or Two Factor for **more than one** accounts above?

**Background**

I have a mid-2012 Retina, a 2016 MacBook Pro, Watch 2, and iPhone 7.

I use the same iCloud account on all devices, therefore I can only use **two factor** authentication for one account listed above.

When I try to reenabled "two step" authentication for the other accounts, I don't see the option anymore within the idmsa portal.

How do I enable either 2 step, or 2 factor in the above scenarios?

Comment: You can hook up 2FA to your phone number and receive codes as texts for multiple accounts on the same iPhone.

Comment: @owlswipe I no longer see that option under the security tab

Answer (score 2):

#### [Two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915)

Macworld has a great tip on [enabling two-factor authentication for an iTunes-only Apple ID](https://www.macworld.com/article/3200035/security/how-to-update-to-two-factor-authentication-for-an-itunes-only-apple-id.html) (or any Apple ID not being used as the iCloud account on an iOS device):

1. Add a new user account on your (or a friend's) Mac.
2. In the new user account, log into iCloud with your iTunes-only Apple ID.
3. Enable two-factor authentication (iCloud preference pane > Account Details > Security tab).

It may be a bit cumbersome to switch to this Mac user account though, if you need to manage your Apple ID often.

Macworld also has some tips on [using your trusted phone number(s) to receive verification codes](https://www.macworld.com/article/3198110/security/can-windows-be-used-with-apple-s-two-factor-authentication.html) when you don't have a trusted device nearby.

#### [Two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204152)

It may no longer be visible in the Apple ID web management interface, but you can still enable two-step verification if you want:

- From the [Apple Support page for two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204152), under the section **How do I set up two-step verification?**, click the link "Set up two-step verification now."; **or**
- Click this link: https://appleid.apple.com/manage/security/2sv/enrollment

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enable two-step authentication for the iTunes account by going to appleid.apple.com and logging in on that account. It's an option under the Security section. I just did this (and I have a similar setup to yours) and it works. You won't be able to use the option of allowing notifications to be sent to devices using Find my iPhone, since they are presumably using your iCloud account. The developer account I'm afraid I can't help on.

It would certainly be nice if we could enable two-factor authentication instead, but I can't find any way to do that.

Comment: You will need to turn off two-step verification before you can enable two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I can only manage one such “two” account so I have my personal account protected with the extra steps / no more security questions.

We use 1Password at work, so my work account has a pretty long password and totally made up long passphrases for each security question and the details are escrowed with 1Password teams so that my peers aren’t locked out if I cannot be reached for whatever reason.

For your iTunes account, I suggest “Family Sharing” so that the majority of the purchases can all fall under the main personal AppleID.